# Not enough values to unpack expected two got one

Tags: python, django

i was following the tutorials on the django official documentation on a polling app, in part 4 of the tutorial i used same code as in the tutorials but i keep getting an error 
ValueError: Not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
here is the code for my views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from django.urls import reverse

from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question



class IndexView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'


    def get_queryset(self):

        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]



class DetailView(generic.DetailView):

    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'



class ResultView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'



def votes(request, question_id):

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    try:


        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(request.POST['choice'])

    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):

        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', 
        {'question':question, 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice",})

    else:

        selected_choice.votes += 1 
        selected_choice.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:resullts', args=(question_id,)))
```

and the html code for detail.html is below

```html
<p>{{question.question_text}}</p>

{% if error_message %}<p>{{error_message}}</p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:votes' question.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{choice.id}}" >
    <label for="choice{{forloop.counter}}">{{choice.choice_text}}</label><br>
{% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

```
Internal Server Error: /polls/1/votes/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\polls\views.py", line 45, in votes
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(kii)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1351, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1378, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\Oj Philz\Desktop\hello\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1248, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is the error message i keep getting

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?  In particular, it would be helpful to know which line the error refers to.

Comment: It is not readable in comments. Edit your question and include it there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code here, I think what you are trying to do is get a choice related to the Question and that also has the choice from the form

```
def votes(request, question_id):

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    try:
        selected_choice = Choice.objects.get(
           question=question,
           id=request.POST['choice']
        ) # UPDATED CODE

    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):

        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', 
        {'question':question, 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice",})
....
```

Comment: i tried it, it didn't work  i got an error                                                                         
 "Cannot resolve keyword 'choice' into field. Choices are: choice_text, id, question, question_id, votes"

Comment: What value comes from `request.POST['choice']`??

Answer (score -1):

I think i figured out the answer, the problem is in the vote function.
The correct code should be

```py
def votes(request, question_id):

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(id=request.POST['choice'])

    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):

        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', 
        {'question':question, 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice",})
```